# How to write correct array string parameter for mysql query?

Tags: mysql, array, parameter, string

I'm trying to put up a correct string to pass as a parameter to a simple query.

Correct query that returns records:

```
SELECT id_s FROM group_of_id_s
WHERE date IN ('2020-08-01','2020-08-01','2020-08-02','2020-08-03','2020-08-04');
```

...but if I pass this (''2020-08-01','2020-08-01','2020-08-02','2020-08-03','2020-08-04'') as a parameter it doesn't work.

I also tried to pass this ('2020-08-01,2020-08-01,2020-08-02,2020-08-03,2020-08-04')

... but it also doesn't work.

My idea is to put this string as a parameter through a procedure.
Perhaps like this:

```
IN parameter TEXT

BEGIN

SET @c = CONCAT('SELECT id_s FROM group_of_id_s
WHERE date IN (', '''' , parameter, '''', ')');

PREPARE stmt from @c;
EXECUTE stmt;

END
```

any reference or helpful advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT: Based on very helpful example from @nbk and changing date format before comparing it to an array, I managed to put up a valid query that works like a charm. You can see it below in all of its glory. ;O) Response from @nbk is therefore considered as solution. Thanky you very much @nbk.**

```
SELECT id_s FROM group_of_id_s
WHERE find_in_set(DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d'), parameter) > 0;
```

Comment: There is no straightforward way to pass an "array" into `IN`.

Comment: I see.. fortunately @nbk proposed 'find in set', and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [find_in_Set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE group_of_id_s (id_s int ,`date`date);

INSERT INTO group_of_id_s VALUES(1,'2020-08-01'),(2,'2020-07-01');


delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc (IN parameter TEXT)
       BEGIN
         SELECT id_s FROM group_of_id_s
         WHERE find_in_set(`date`, parameter) > 0;
       END//
delimiter ;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
CALL myproc("2020-08-01,2020-08-01,2020-08-02,2020-08-03,2020-08-04");

| id_s |
| ---- |
| 1    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFQtPUnQsJc4cPWb4tGoyQ/7)